# Spring Integration - Controlling Auto-Startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have an Inbound File Channel Adapter with the `auto-startup` property set to `false`. This adapter is the starting point for my application; if it sends no messages notifying the system of files, I expect everything else to be inert.

However, upon starting my context, messages start flowing through the system. Why?

Config:

```xml
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter auto-startup="false" id="fileWatcher" directory="${input.dir}" channel="incomingFiles">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"></int:poller>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="incomingFiles"></int:channel>
```

Main method:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    logger.info("Started application");
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/spring-config/*.xml");
    context.start();
}
```

Logs:

```
[...]
12:06:56.743 [main] INFO  o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter - started fileWatcher
12:06:56.770 [task-scheduler-6] INFO  o.s.i.file.FileReadingMessageSource - Created message: [[Payload=C:\input\From Spreadsheet.txt][Headers={timestamp=1343214416770, id=b8e92486-d469-406e-8787-df78e23b287a}]]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

set auto-startup="false" on the adapter (it is true by default).

You can manually start it getting a reference to it and call fileWatcher.start(). This is also available over JMX if you include the integration MBean exporter.

Or, you can send a message to a <control-bus /> containing '@fileWatcher.start()' in its payload.

Oh; I just noticed you have it already.

DON'T call context.start() - that will start all the beans, regardless of their auto-startup setting.

auto-startups controls, err, AUTO startup - you are manually starting the context.

Comment: Thanks Gary! I didn't realise that construction was enough to implicitly 'start' beans.